# Where can I find Python Word Mover's Distance Code

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to find pure python code for Word Mover's Distance Code. 
Found in pyemd but code with c. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=wmd&type=Repositories

There are a few pure-python results here, for example[image: ByronPan sWMD]

Comment: Thank you for your message. Not sure, is this the original WMD? Checked all results, they resued existing code from gensim or pyemd.